# DatePeriod does not show 00:00

Tags: php

I create an attendance system for employees working in a company and I need to check the time intervals while adding records. So I have to create an array of hours. With the `DatePeriod`, I output hours in a certain time interval. It works but does not show anything when 00:00 is in two different time intervals.

Normally it should output the following range:

- 00:00
- 01:00
- 02:00
- 03:00
- 04:00

But shows nothing.

```
<?php

    $a = '23:00';
    $b = '05:00';

    $period = new DatePeriod(
        new DateTime($a),
        new DateInterval('PT1H'),
        new DateTime($b),
        DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE
    );
    foreach ($period as $date) {
        echo $date->format("H:i\n");
    }

?>
```

Thank you

Comment: var_dump the period... you intialize DateTime with only a time, so it uses the current day. And then 05:00 is _before_ 23:00. Edit: why not use DatePeriod with only start and $recurrences ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dump dates you pass to DatePeriod you will see they are both today so your start date is after the end date. And really you mean in this case: give me hours between today 23:00 and tomorrow 05:00 - so if this happen just add 1 day to your end date.

```
<?php

    $a = '23:00';
    $b = '05:00';

    $aDate = new DateTime($a);
    $bDate = new DateTime($b);

    if ($aDate > $bDate) {
      $bDate->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    }

    $period = new DatePeriod(
        $aDate,
        new DateInterval('PT1H'),
        $bDate,
        DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE
    );
    foreach ($period as $date) {
        echo $date->format("H:i\n");
    }
```

Output:

```
00:00
01:00
02:00
03:00
04:00
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I got it. :)